# To convert variable name to string or symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, string-to-symbol

it's possible in rails convert variable name to string?

Example:
`stack_overflow = "Fantastic!".`

by `stack_overflow.to_sym` I'll get `:Fantastic!`.
Instead I would  => `:stack_overflow`

and, if it were possibile, this would be bad programming cause unsafe code?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Why would you need that? In your code just set the variable to be the name you want, or the parameters from the user

Comment: In the methods, I have some instructions that are repeated because they do the same thing: they set an hash with symbol => value. 
The value is passed by a parameter, instead the name of the symbol is static because it solely depends from the method, and also, the symbol must be different in each method. 
So I would know if there is something that does an "eval" on the name of variable and  consequently to DRY code. 
Your idea is good ( pass symbol through parameter ) but I wanted to confort myself with others :-)
thank you!

Comment: I would suggest posting your code and asking how to make it dry, rather than what you're suggesting.  It sounds like you can extract the repeated sections into a method.

Comment: Hi Japed, sorry for late.
My question was really simple, I also asked if it would be a good way of programming. But, can i receive a specific answer? That's: it is possible or no? :)
thank u!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use [`eval()`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval), although I don't know the specific way you'd achieve what you want:

`new_var = eval(stack_overflow.to_sym)`